# Como exibir na tela o push que fiz no array?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma lista com url de jpgs e eles estao exibidos na tela pelo for. Tenho uma function no botão para adicionar novos jpgs. O console mostra com sucesso o endereço de  jpeg que é adicionado, mas ele não entra na tela que nem os outros que estão já no array.

```js
var listaFilmes = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/8/8a/Into-the-wild.jpg",
"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzk0NDg1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDg0NjkxMDI@._V1_.jpg",
"https://flxt.tmsimg.com/assets/p40_p_v10_ap.jpg",
"https://image.posterlounge.pt/images/big/1873454.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/b/b2/Out_of_Africa.jpg"]

function adicionarFilme(){
  var url = document.getElementById("filme").value;
  listaFilmes.push(url);
  console.log(url);
  console.log(listaFilmes);
 
}

for (i=0; i<listaFilmes.length; i++){
  document.write("<img src="+listaFilmes[i]+">");
}
```

```html
filmesNaTela<div class="container">
  <h1 class="page-title">
 Lista de Filmes
  </h1>

</div>
 <p class="page-subtitle">
      Qual seu filme favorito?
    </p>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <input type="text" id="filme" name="filme" placeholder="Insira endereço de imagem">
      <button onClick="adicionarFilme()">Adicionar Filme</button>
    </div>
<div id="filmesNaTela"></div>
```

Comment: Coloca `document.write("<img src="+url+">");` no final da sua função `adicionarFilme`.

Comment: Se faço isso ele não entra no for. Ele não é colocado lado a lado na tela com as outras imgens. O jpeg até é exibido, mas sozinho e fora da área do css.. É estranho, pois ele vai pra lista, mas não entra nas condições do for.

Comment: No lugar de concatenar pensou em usar template string...?

Answer (score -2):

Tentei da seguinte forma e deu certo:

```
function adicionarFilme(){
  var url = document.getElementById("filme").value;
  listaFilmes.push(url);
  console.table(listaFilmes);
  listarFilmes();
}

function listarFilmes(){
  for (i=0; i<listaFilmes.length; i++){
    document.write("<img src="+listaFilmes[i]+">");
  }
}
```

Se caso a imagem esteja saindo fora do que você espera no seu layout, provavelmente você precisa especificar aonde você quer que ele faça o `document.write("<img src="+listaFilmes[i]+">");`

Faça a função for encontrar a div que você quer e faça um append dentro do elemento, veja essa documentação acho que te ajudará:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_node_appendchild.asp

Answer (score -2):

O erro, em resumo, é porque você adiciona a URL no array, mas em nenhum momento você atualiza esse array na tela, então ele só mostra as imagens definidas previamente. Uma forma de corrigir isso SEM MANTER as imagens fixas é criar outra função e chamá-la dentro da função `adicionarFilme()`:

```js
var listaFilmes = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/8/8a/Into-the-wild.jpg",
"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzk0NDg1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDg0NjkxMDI@._V1_.jpg",
"https://flxt.tmsimg.com/assets/p40_p_v10_ap.jpg",
"https://image.posterlounge.pt/images/big/1873454.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/b/b2/Out_of_Africa.jpg"]

function adicionarFilme(){
  var url = document.getElementById("filme").value;
  listaFilmes.push(url);
  mostrarFilmes();
}

function mostrarFilmes(){
  for (i=0; i<listaFilmes.length; i++){
    document.write("<img src="+listaFilmes[i]+">");
  }
}
```

E se você quiser manter o array estático você pode repetir a estrutura `for` dentro da função:

```js
var listaFilmes = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/8/8a/Into-the-wild.jpg",
"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzk0NDg1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDg0NjkxMDI@._V1_.jpg",
"https://flxt.tmsimg.com/assets/p40_p_v10_ap.jpg",
"https://image.posterlounge.pt/images/big/1873454.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/b/b2/Out_of_Africa.jpg"]

for (i=0; i<listaFilmes.length; i++){
    document.write("<img src="+listaFilmes[i]+">");
}

function adicionarFilme(){
  var url = document.getElementById("filme").value;
  listaFilmes.push(url);
  for (i=0; i<listaFilmes.length; i++){
    document.write("<img src="+listaFilmes[i]+">");
  }
}
```

Não é a solução mais performática ou recomendada, mas como você está aprendendo acho que é suficiente para entender como funções funcionam e como elas se relacionam com botões.